# Confirmation as two buttons replacing one with previous interaction

Tags: buttons, confirmation

Recently heard an idea to show confirmation buttons directly in place of an element(button), that had interaction, that led to confirmation.

The question is should the button be replaced with or maybe confirmation buttons should be added below. Not quite sure.

Maybe it would be enough, to leave first button text as text so that person would remember, what he is confirming/rejecting.

Example: http://plnkr.co/edit/KKdPlPVYuyhNK154Xstc?p=preview

Comment: why do you need one additional steps for this? Can it come in modal?

Comment: No. Modal isn't very friendly for mobile devices, therefore modal is not an option. Same goes for an old prompt window approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are dealing with space constraints, I would suggest a compromise between UXfrom12 and Eugene:

Keep the first button labeled "Would you like to remove your account?" On click, display the two buttons, but with the labels "Yes, remove my account" and "Cancel". This way it's always clear to the user what they're doing, even when showing/hiding buttons.

Comment: Yep. Going with it. It will be in the form of popover. One UX person suggested to use it instead of modal. It doesn't loose context from sight and at the same time it allows person to focus on slightly different area on page. As an example: http://plnkr.co/edit/VQIjLD6nVjRcX3z0Gj7T?p=preview

Answer (score 1):

I'm not keen, but that's only my view. It seems a little strange that the button it the question, which switches to a confirm or cancel choice, when you could just have the label above "Would you like to remove your account?" And two button below "Yes, remove my account" and "No, cancel."

These present the user with the question and answer in the a more traditional style with negative and positive actions forming part of the question.

Comment: It requires more space I would say if user does not require do this action at the moment. Therefore it did seem logical to first show the button with provided action. Do not get me wrong, I think, that showing original question as a text after initial button was interacted with seems like a good idea.

Comment: Not a lot more space and it's more user friendly, but you're free to implement what you think your users need. I generally find showing and hiding buttons to be not a great experience.

Answer (score 0):

My concern here would be users propensity to double click on desktops, less of an issue on mobile.

The second click could result in an action occurring that they did not want.

Take your example, if you have your mouse mid-button and double click you hit reject.  If "reject" has a downstream workflow that is extremely adverse that could cause real problems.

Answer (score 0):

I am also not sure that the question should be on the button. Buttons make an actions or answer a question. But they can not ask a question. I would change the label to "Remove account". And if you have space constrains, I would make a popup confirmation, explaining that the action is irreversible and what this action specifically does (what data will be removed, what services won't be available and etc.). This way user can certainly answer the question if he is sure or not.